# Running Azure Function Net5 (dotnet-isolated) in Linux Container generate error - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\site\wwwroot/

Tags: linux, azure, azure-functions, containers, dotnet-isolated

I have a Azure Function App running in a Linux Container with the following Specs

1. `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`
2. `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>`
3. `"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"`

The function runs fine locally, but when i deploy it to the cloud I'm getting error **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\site\wwwroot/** . I've copied the log trace below which has the error mesage in it. Please help as I've been on this issue for a while now.

**--Main Class--**

```
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureCustomFunctionsWorker()
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

**--Class with DI--**

```
    public static class CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IHostBuilder ConfigureCustomFunctionsWorker(this IHostBuilder builder)
        {..
          ..  }
}
```

**--My Function--**

```
[Function("UpdateContentMetadata")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/60 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Function ran in a linux container.");
}
```

**--My Docker File--**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:3.0-dotnet-isolated5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1 as runtime3_1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
# Copy .NET Core 3.1 runtime from the 3.1 image
COPY --from=runtime3_1 /usr/share/dotnet/host /usr/share/dotnet/host
COPY --from=runtime3_1 /usr/share/dotnet/shared /usr/share/dotnet/shared
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Functions/Functions.csproj", "Functions/"]
COPY ["ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj", "ApplicationCore/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Functions/Functions.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Functions"
RUN dotnet build "Functions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Functions.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

**--Function Project file--**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AssemblyName>Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions</RootNamespace>
    <DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>/home/site/wwwroot</DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <None Remove="deploy.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="deploy.ps1">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.17">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ApplicationCore\ApplicationCore.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**--The logs trace--**

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher.InitializeJobhostLanguageWorkerChannelAsync(??) at /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Workers/Rpc/FunctionRegistration/RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher.cs : 112\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass53_0.<StartWorkerProcesses>b__0(??) at /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Workers/Rpc/FunctionRegistration/RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher.cs : 186','exceptionMessage':'A task was canceled.','exceptionType':'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException'}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.329570078Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Triggers.Timer[5]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.329609178Z: [INFO]        The next 5 occurrences of the 'UpdateMordinaContentMetadata' schedule (Cron: '0 * * * * *') will be:

2022-07-05T16:10:26.329616178Z: [INFO]        07/05/2022 16:11:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:11:00Z)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.330522482Z: [INFO]        07/05/2022 16:12:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:12:00Z)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.330540183Z: [INFO]        07/05/2022 16:13:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:13:00Z)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.330545783Z: [INFO]        07/05/2022 16:14:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:14:00Z)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.330559083Z: [INFO]        07/05/2022 16:15:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:15:00Z)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.330565183Z: [INFO]        

2022-07-05T16:10:26.337669319Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'The next 5 occurrences of the UpdateMordinaContentMetadata schedule (Cron: 0 * * * * *) will be:\n07/05/2022 16:11:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:11:00Z)\n07/05/2022 16:12:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:12:00Z)\n07/05/2022 16:13:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:13:00Z)\n07/05/2022 16:14:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:14:00Z)\n07/05/2022 16:15:00+00:00 (07/05/2022 16:15:00Z)\n','category':'Host.Triggers.Timer','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','functionName':'UpdateMordinaContentMetadata','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1,'eventId':5,'eventName':'NextOccurrences'}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.373387803Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Host started (1193ms)','category':'Host.Startup','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1,'eventId':413,'eventName':'ScriptHostStarted'}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.374396409Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Job host started','category':'Host.Startup','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.377892227Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Startup[413]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.377913327Z: [INFO]        Host started (1193ms)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.378812531Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Startup[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.378829531Z: [INFO]        **Job host started**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.393426407Z: [INFO]  info: **Function.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata[1]**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.393481507Z: [INFO]        Executing 'Functions.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-07-05T16:10:26.3470099+00:00', Id=dfa7ebb1-fba0-4a75-a3da-6b3e2c9e5832)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.432553908Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Executing Functions.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata (Reason=Timer fired at 2022-07-05T16:10:26.3470099+00:00, Id=dfa7ebb1-fba0-4a75-a3da-6b3e2c9e5832)','category':'Function.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','functionInvocationId':'dfa7ebb1-fba0-4a75-a3da-6b3e2c9e5832','functionName':'Functions.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1,'eventId':1,'eventName':'FunctionStarted'}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.433993416Z: [INFO]  info: Function.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.434024216Z: [INFO]        Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2022-07-05T09:24:00.0000000+00:00

2022-07-05T16:10:26.435659424Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2022-07-05T09:24:00.0000000+00:00','category':'Function.UpdateMordinaContentMetadata','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','functionInvocationId':'dfa7ebb1-fba0-4a75-a3da-6b3e2c9e5832','functionName':'UpdateMordinaContentMetadata','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.440603250Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production

2022-07-05T16:10:26.452215909Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /azure-functions-host

2022-07-05T16:10:26.452862413Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:80

2022-07-05T16:10:26.453557416Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

2022-07-05T16:10:26.524916784Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 2,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\\site\\wwwroot/','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Error','levelId':4,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.526059590Z: [INFO]  fail: **Host.Function.Console[0]**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.526077790Z: [INFO]        Unhandled exception. **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\site\wwwroot/**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.530210311Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.530230911Z: [INFO]           at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.532626424Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.532646324Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.532652424Z: [INFO]           at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.539172457Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.540497764Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.543584380Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions.BuildConfiguration(IServiceCollection services) in **/src/Functions/Startup.cs:line** 94','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.543605880Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.543612480Z: [INFO]           at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.543617180Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.543634580Z: [INFO]           at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions.BuildConfiguration(IServiceCollection services) in **/src/Functions/Startup.cs:line 94**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549548311Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<ConfigureCustomFunctionsWorker>b__0_3(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection serviceCollection) in **/src/Functions/Startup.cs:line** 45','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549571811Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549578911Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549584311Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549589011Z: [INFO]           at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<ConfigureCustomFunctionsWorker>b__0_3(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection serviceCollection) in **/src/Functions/Startup.cs:line 45**

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549594211Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549598511Z: [INFO]           at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549602611Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.549606711Z: [INFO]           at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

2022-07-05T16:10:26.554974739Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Functions/Program.cs:line 11','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:26.555002739Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.555017939Z: [INFO]           at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Functions/Program.cs:line 11

2022-07-05T16:10:26.555023439Z: [INFO]  info: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:26.555027839Z: [INFO]           at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

2022-07-05T16:10:26.555032239Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.Program.<Main>(String[] args)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:26

2022-07-05T16:10:30.192339115Z: [INFO]  info: Host.General[337]

2022-07-05T16:10:30.192380715Z: [INFO]        Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d'.

2022-07-05T16:10:30.194725228Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d.','category':'Host.General','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1,'eventId':337,'eventName':'PrimaryHostCoordinatorLockLeaseAcquired'}",07/05/2022 16:10:30

2022-07-05T16:10:36.889513201Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 2,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\\site\\wwwroot/','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Error','levelId':4,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:36

2022-07-05T16:10:36.891593012Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:36

2022-07-05T16:10:36.892824119Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:36

2022-07-05T16:10:36.893620623Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:36

2022-07-05T16:10:36.898783450Z: [INFO]  MS_FUNCTION_AZURE_MONITOR_EVENT 4,int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func.azurewebsites.net,Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log,FunctionAppLogs,,"{'appName':'int-Mordina-content-subscriber-func','roleInstance':'5eff078071531b34fa16e69b598af76d1be5dfdf78b917c067816f3eea5e617b','message':'   at Mordina.Content.Subscriber.Functions.CustomWorkerHostBuilderExtensions.BuildConfiguration(IServiceCollection services) in **/src/Functions/Startup.cs:line** 94','category':'Host.Function.Console','hostVersion':'3.8.2.0','hostInstanceId':'3ed51ac4-8e7b-46f0-8f72-816e2cd7618a','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",07/05/2022 16:10:36

2022-07-05T16:10:36.901757566Z: [INFO]  fail: Host.Function.Console[0]

2022-07-05T16:10:36.901831367Z: [INFO]        Unhandled exception. **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home\site\wwwroot/**
```